# Basis, Alternative, Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis

I'm trying to understand the practical purpose of using the basis vectors vs. alternative basis..and when you would want to/need to change the basis. Data Science related application would be especially useful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is necessarily the kind of application you are looking for, but changing the basis is particularly important with respect to [diagonalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization). Diagonal matrices can simplify many common matrix operations, so if we can find a basis with respect to which the matrix of a linear transformation is a diagonal matrix, then we'll find many things (eigenvectors, eigenvalues, computing powers) much simpler.